# Why did nobody know who the Lord of Storm's End was?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S08E04

> Gendry became the Lord of the Storm's End.

There was a really strange situation in the hall of Winterfell before that: Daenerys asked if anyone knew who the current Lord was and nobody answered, as if nobody knew. Tyrion, Varys, Sam Tarly, Bran with all his super-powers... they were all there in the room and yet nobody answered.

Did really none of them know the answer? Was there another reason they all kept silent?

Comment: Bran lives mostly in the past now.

Comment: Do you know what a rhetorical question is? That was one, and so is this.

Comment: @Gaius I don't think it was a rhetorical question. She repeated the question more than once, she waited for the answer risking someone would say: "Yeah, the current Lord is this guy.", which would be really embarrassing for the Queen.

Comment: Realm is in chaos. They don't even all know(or agree) who should be the ruler of all seven kingdoms. Why should they know who rules one of kingdoms right now?

Comment: @vojta you're a lord of the north, your king just got dominated by a foreign conqueror who claims to own half the planet and she asks who owns a nearby territory. Are you going to be the one to answer?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well that is because there was no Lord of Storm's End as far as they knew or we know. Nobles grow up learning about other noble families' family trees, particularly their neighbours and great Houses.

Had Daenerys asked that Question after Robert died, they'd have all answered Renly Baratheon. Had she asked that question after Renly died, their answer would have been Stannis Baratheon. Had she asked that after Stannis died (And Shireen had been alive), their answer would have been Shireen Baratheon (Or Lord Stannis' little girl for those who couldn't recall her name).

Yet as it happened, the known Baratheons were all dead at that moment, the real and the feigned ones.

1. Robert Baratheon (Dead)

   1.1. Joffrey *Baratheon* (Dead)

   1.2. Tommen *Baratheon* (Dead)

   1.3. Myrcella *Baratheon* (Dead)
2. Stannis Baratheon (Dead)

   2.1. Shireen Baratheon (Dead)
3. Renly Baratheon (Dead)

Nobody knows any other Baratheon, nor have they heard any news of a Stormlander resurgence after Stannis' demise. So as far as they can guess, Storm's End lacks a lord and so do the Stormlands as a whole. The silence was the answer. Why Bran refused to answer? Well only Bran can tell but if we had to venture a guess I'd say that is because Bran has repeatedly told people that he doesn't really feel or need anything, he's mostly apathetic to whatever is happening around him. Most likely he never heard the question or if he did hear, he just didn't deign to answer it.

Comment: I think in cases like this the lands default to the crown, so after Stannis died it would have been... Tommen? But he's dead as well, and Daenerys isn't likely to consider that line of succession legitimate anyway. I'd say she's ruler of the Stromlands by right of conquest, really. Either way, it's messy, and I probably wouldn't have bothered to speak up either, since she clearly had something in mind.

Comment: @Geobits You're correct in that assumption, if a house goes extinct, the Lands revert to the crown. But Tommen, when he held the Crown, did so as a Baratheon. So officially the house didn't go extinct back then and Tommen legally inherited it as heir of his uncle Stannis (Although I believe he had signed a bill of attainder against Stannis before that). The confusion starts with Cersei. Cersei is no Baratheon. The reason stormlords are so fiercely loyal to Baratheons is because they are not just some upjumped foreigners imposed by Aegon I, they are heirs to ancient Storm Kings

Comment: And since no Stormlander appears to be serving Cersei, unlike Ironborn, Reachmen and Westermen - It is safe to say that they did not join Cersei's illegitimate government - And lacking a leader, they are still disorganised.

Comment: *"The confusion starts with Cersei"* - True of so many things

Comment: Why would Renly have inherited Storm's End before Stannis? Shouldn't Stannis (the middle brother) gain title before Renly (the youngest brother)? For that matter, shouldn't Tommen have priority before both of them (assuming titles are split and didn't all go to Joffrey)?

Comment: @MichaelW. You are correct that Stannis should have gotten Storm's End and Lord Stannis himself agrees with you :D Robert however chose to give Storm's End to Renly and Dragonstone to Stannis. Stannis always considered himself cheated of his rights. But since the cup passed to Renly, it was him who held Storm's End when Robert died. And no, succession in Westeros is Primogeniture, not Gavelkind. Which means the firstborn gets all the titles, younger children get nothing unless their father gives them something in his life.

Comment: Now you might be wondering, "Okay so why didn't Joffrey get precedence over his uncles?". Because Robert gave them away in his life in perpetuity. When he became King, he moved to KL and King traditionally holds only Crownlands. So he gave his ancestral seat to his younger brother and the traditional seat of the heir apparent to his middle brother. And he did so in perpetuity, not on understanding that Lands would revert on the holder's death as Jaehaerys I did when he gave Dragonstone to his sister Rhaena. Had Robert held all those lands when he died, Joffrey would have inherited them

Comment: I just wanted to point out that Stannis Baratheon didn't really die on screen. So you might hade to revise his status to "presumed dead" in a few days when the last episode airs...

Comment: @pgsandstrom I thought most of us had passed the first stage of grief: Denial? ;)

Comment: @Aegon Actually, the Baratheons are not the heirs to the ancient Storm Kings, who were from House Durrandon. During Aegon I Targaryen's years of the Conquest, Orys Baratheon slew the last Storm King and took his lands by right of conquest.  Orys was also Aegon's Hand of the King. There have always been rumors that Orys was in truth Aegon's bastard half-brother, and even more scurrilous rumors that Orys and Aegon were once lovers in their youth—could it be that the Conqueror named his son the future king *Aenys* because of the euphonic pairing with the name *Orys*? Quel homage! :)

Comment: @tchrist Have you read _Fire and Blood: Vol 1_? In it, it is confirmed that Orys was brother to Aegon, Visenya and Rhaenys. And you forget, Orys not only slew the last Storm King Argilac the Arrogant, he also married his only daughter, the Princess Argella Durrandon and took her coat of arms as his own. Baratheons are heirs to Durrandons through Argella. Orys did not take the land by right of conquest, he did so in Aegon's name who'd taken it by right of conquest. Orys himself held the land by grace of Aegon Targaryen, his royal brother, not by force of arms.

Comment: @tchrist About Orys and Aegon being lovers and Aenys named after him, well I'd say it's a very dubious theory, more like fan-fic. Given Targaryen incest custom, it wouldn't be surprising if the two half brothers took up jousting in a different way but from what we know, Orys was loyal to his own wife, Aegon to his wives. Neither are known to have any paramours. And there's no indication that they were homosexual. Aenys sound like Orys means nothing really. Rhaenys sounds like Orys too, In fact a lot of Valyrian names end up sounding like that.